# Finding the roots of the following equation

Tags: logarithms

$$v(t) = u\ln\left({\frac{m_0}{m_0-\alpha t}}\right)-gt $$
Is the typical equation for the velocity of a rocket under gravity, with no air drag. Now I want to solve it, but I have no idea how to solve it for $v(t) = 0$. Clearly one solution is $t_1=0$. Plugging in the values numerically ($m_0 = 70000, u = 2500, g = 10, \alpha = 250$) Mathematica tells me the second root is $t_2 = 57.7766$

How can I solve this equation? I tried rewriting $t = \ln{e^t}$ but this didn't help me at all as I end up with an equation of the type $g(t,e^t) = 0$.

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a transcendental equation, and there are probably no closed form solutions. However, you can use a series approximation:
$$\ln\left(\frac{1}{1-x}\right)\approx x+ \frac{x^2}{2} +  \frac{x^3}{3}+\ldots$$
To get:
$$gt = u \ln \left(\frac{m}{m-\alpha t}\right)=
u \ln \left(\frac{1}{1-(\alpha/m) t}\right)\approx
u (\alpha/m) t + u\frac{(\alpha/m)^2 t^2}{2}$$
Leading to:
$$\frac{u\alpha^2}{2m^2}t \approx(g - (u\alpha/m))$$
$$t\approx \frac{2m^2(g - (u\alpha/m))}{u\alpha^2}\approx 67 \ \text{sec}$$
Which isn't that far off from your $57.78$. If you keep the cubic term in the approximation, you'll get a quadratic equation which you can solve to get $t\approx 59\ \text{sec}$, which is even closer.

Comment: thank you! You said that probably there are no closed solutions. Is there a way to know if there are any?

Comment: @Euler_Salter - by a closed form solution I meant a solution expressible using elementary functions. You could always invent a new function that satisfies your solution, or in this case use the Lambert W function.

Comment: can I just ask you how you went about approximating $\ln{\left(\frac{1}{1-x}\right)}$? Did you use the Taylor's expansion? Around which point?